# How to tap on the Textview the buttons appear/disappear?

Tags: android

I'm making a program that change the color of the background, for example, when I press white, change background to white, black to black, and so on... and after have pressed a button the others disappear and I have already done that but what I want to do is that each tap on the Textview the buttons appear/disappear. how can I do this?

this is my code

```
LinearLayout myLayout;
    LinearLayout myLayout2;
    // Declare UI elements
    private Button firstButton;
    private Button secondButton, thirdButton;
//    private ImageView changeBackground;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 


        myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
        myLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout2);

        // Initialize the UI components



        firstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        // When we creating a button and if we expect that to use for event handling we have to set the listener
        firstButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        secondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        secondButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        thirdButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        thirdButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



@Override
    public void onClick(View v) { // Parameter v stands for the view that was clicked.  

        switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
            myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            myLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            myLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            myLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;


        }

    }
```

the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#A9F5F2"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/myLayout2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="#D8D8D8"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:gravity="center"
             tools:context=".MainActivity" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
                android:text="@string/white" />



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
                android:text="@string/black" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:text="@string/red" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your question is fairly vague.  Tell us what IS happening and post your xml layout (or java layout code if you did it that way).  Additionally, is the myLayout2... line under each case a copy-paste error or is that intended?

Comment: I have add whole my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
myLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
               myLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

and change this:

```
myLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

to:

```
 myLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Just to explain why you need to use GONE instead of INVISIBLE, if you set the visibility to INVISIBLE the object will continue to alter to exist in the screen, you just can't see the object... and when you use GONE the object doesn't exist on the screen but exist in the app instance.

Comment: Ok. What I'm doing is if I press a button this button change the background for example button1 = White and the other buttons disappear after I pressed the button1. but then if I tap on the screen, it should appear again the buttons to be able to choose another button.

Comment: Works but the buttons don't appear again

Comment: add myLayout2.setVisibility(View.Visible); after the myLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Just remove the myLayout.setVisibility ... now I tested this code alter the visibility for the myLayout doesn't make any sense since that layout is the main parent...

Comment: Another thing... don't use View.INVISIBLE , use View.GONE

Comment: Now works :) and one more question, if I just want to hide/unhide the buttons by touching the screen whithout pressing a button what else I should add?

Comment: just add an if on your myLayout.clickListener if(myLayout2.getVisibility()!=View.GONE)  myLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE); else  myLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

If you want your button to disappear with all his characteristics use :

```
 myLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

instead of

```
 myLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

INVISIBLE:

```
 This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
```

GONE:

```
 This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
```

Comment: Ok. But what I want to do next, if I tap on the textview, it should appear again the buttons in order to be able to press another button

Comment: After if you want your button to appear again do  myLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);